# How to create tekton task for building a docker slim?

Tags: docker, tekton

Has anyone tried to create tekton task on building a docker slim?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out we can re-use the "dind-sidecar" sample from the tekton pipelines repository:
https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/main/examples/v1alpha1/taskruns/dind-sidecar.yaml

I got it working using the following:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: docker-build-dockerslim
spec:
  params:
  - default: docker.io/dslim/docker-slim:latest
    description: The location of the kaniko builder image.
    name: builderimage
    type: string
  - default: docker.io/docker:stable
    description: The location of the Docker builder image.
    name: pushimage
    type: string
  - default: "registry.default.svc.cluster.local:5000"
    description: When using an insecure (for push/pull to a non-TLS registry), we should set its name here. Don't set an empty string, remove option from task or set it to a dummy value if not required.
    name: insecure
    type: string
  - default: docker.io/docker:dind
    description: The location of the Docker in Docker image.
    name: dindimage
    type: string
  - default: Dockerfile
    description: The name of the Dockerfile
    name: dockerfile
    type: string
  - default: .
    description: Parent directory for your Dockerfile.
    name: dockerroot
    type: string
  resources:
    inputs:
    - name: source
      type: git
    outputs:
    - name: image
      type: image
  steps:
  - args:
    - --state-path
    - /dslim-state
    - --in-container
    - build
    - --http-probe=false
    - --dockerfile
    - $(inputs.params.dockerfile)
    - --dockerfile-context
    - $(inputs.params.dockerroot)
    - $(outputs.resources.image.url)
    env:
    - name: DOCKER_HOST
      value: tcp://127.0.0.1:2376
    - name: DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
      value: '1'
    - name: DOCKER_CERT_PATH
      value: /certs/client
    image: $(inputs.params.builderimage)
    name: build
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /dslim-state
      name: state
    - mountPath: /certs/client
      name: dind-certs
    workingDir: /workspace/source
  - command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - |
        SLIM_IMAGE=$(docker images | awk '/docker-slim.*[0-9]*\.slim/{print $1;exit 0;}')
        docker tag "$SLIM_IMAGE" $(outputs.resources.image.url)
        docker push $(outputs.resources.image.url)
    name: push
    image: $(params.pushimage)
    env:
    - name: DOCKER_HOST
      value: tcp://127.0.0.1:2376
    - name: DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
      value: '1'
    - name: DOCKER_CERT_PATH
      value: /certs/client
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /certs/client
      name: dind-certs
  sidecars:
  - args:
    - --storage-driver=vfs
    - --userland-proxy=false
    - --debug
    - --insecure-registry=$(inputs.params.insecure)
    env:
    - name: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR
      value: /certs
    image: $(inputs.params.dindimage)
    name: dind
    readinessProbe:
      periodSeconds: 1
      exec:
        command:
        - ls
        - /certs/client/ca.pem
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /certs/client
      name: dind-certs
  volumes:
  - name: dind-certs
    emptyDir: {}
  - emptyDir: {}
    name: state
```

For some reason, the resulting images doesn't appear with the name I expected it to. Also tried setting a "--target" argument, though neither this nor the default "last-arg-is-image-name" behavior they document in their readme seems to work ( https://github.com/docker-slim/docker-slim ).

However I did find, listing images, the following:

```
docker-slim-tmp-fat-image.12.20211205135050.slim         latest              0037ff15e1f5        2 seconds ago       13.8MB
docker-slim-empty-image                                  latest              9dfd57fb50a8        35 seconds ago      0B
docker-slim-tmp-fat-image.12.20211205135050              latest              9ad36dd5e3f3        39 seconds ago      211MB
<Dockerfiles-FROM-image>                                 master              f11e63190556        3 months ago        211MB
```

Thus, I do some "docker images | awk ..." then "docker tag xxx.slim the-target-name-I-wanted", before my "docker push".

Resulting image is indeed smaller. I'ld to test this with other images, and make sure it doesn't introduce any regression, ... still, that's interesting.

Comment: submitted a PR to tektonhub catalog: https://github.com/tektoncd/catalog/pull/876